# Firebase: load local data

Tags: android, firebase

I would like to ask for one solution. My project is connect to Firebase (Database and also Storage). I have some query to database as following:

```
documentReference
 .get()
 .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) 
  {
     TODO Something
  });
```

And if the query start it seems, that first step is synchronization with server. I would like to ask you if it is possible to show (get) data from local copy and then start with sync?

The reason is, that in some case I would like to show data the user as soon as possible.

Thank you very much

Marek

Comment: So to understand better, you want to get data only from cache?

Comment: if you want to load pre-loaded or saved data , simply check if data exists then load it and after loading that data call firebase.

Comment: I am sure, that this data has to save local, because I am able to save data without internet. Please do you have any experience how check local data from firebase?

Comment: So you want to get only the local (cached) data, right? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Yes and no. I would like to get local data show it user and then sync with data on server. The reason is simply In some case i don't want to wait on sync (which take some time).